# Real analysis Borel sigma algebra.

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that Borel sigma algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains intervals of the form $[a, b)$, where $a<b$.

I have shown that the Borel sigma algebra contains all of those intervals; $S$ contains the closed interval $[a, b]$ and the single point $b$, so it contains the $[a,b)$.

But I have no clue how to show its the smallest one that contains all the intervals of the form $[a,b)$. I was wondering if any of you could help me. It would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

1. If a $\sigma$-algebra contains all open segments, then it contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
2. You can write $$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [a+\frac{1}{n}, b).$$

Comment: I think that should be $a+\frac{1}{n}$, and $n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash \{0\}$ :)

Comment: @user48805 of course. Corrected.